# Tablib fails to convert JSON API response to XLSX file and throws error KeyError:0

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tablib

I am trying to convert a JSON response I get after calling an API to an excel file. I don't need to add specific headers or get only specific data, I just need everything this call returns.

I have found the `tablib` [library](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/api/).

I managed to make it working when I fetched data from GitLab but after changing my payload to Tfs I get an error which I am not sure what the problem is or how to resolve.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import tablib
import datetime
import time
import os

class gitlab():

    def get_closed():

        url = "https://IP:443/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects"

        payload = {}

        querystring = {"api-version":"4.1"}

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json-patch+json",
            'Authorization': "KEY" 
        }

        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

        response = requests.request(
            "GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, params=querystring,  verify=False)

        return json.loads(response.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    list_b = gitlab.get_closed() 

    print(list_b)
    data = tablib.Dataset()

    data.json = json.dumps(list_b)

    data_export = data.export('xlsx')

    filename = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) +'/closed_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.xlsx'

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
        f.write(data_export)  

    f.close()
```

Executing with `python script` where python's version is `3.7.2` shows the following error:

```
{'count': 1, 'value': [{'id': 'ID', 'name': 'TFS', 'url': 'https://TFS/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/PROJ', 'state': 'wellFormed', 'revision': 00, 'visibility': 'private'}]}

Traceback (most recent call last):  File ".\gitlab.py", line 94, in <module>    data.json = json.dumps(list_with_bugs, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)  File "C:\Users\marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tablib\formats\_json.py", line 39, in import_set
    dset.dict = json.loads(in_stream)
  File "C:\Users\marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tablib\core.py", line 381, in _set_dict
    if isinstance(pickle[0], list):
KeyError: 0
```

You can see the API response as well in the output. Why is tablib failing to convert to excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dataset.json](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/api/#tablib.Dataset.json) expects to receive a serialised list.  The code in the question is passing a serialised `dict`, and this is the cause of the error.

Looking at the data, it seems the value of the `value` key in the dictionary is what is required, so pass that to the dataset.

```
>>> import json
>>> import tablib
>>> d = {'count': 1, 'value': [{'id': 'ID', 'name': 'TFS', 'url': 'https://TFS/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/PROJ', 'state': 'wellFormed', 'revision': 00, 'visibility': 'private'}]}
>>> ds = tablib.Dataset()
>>> ds.json = json.dumps(d['value'])
>>> with open('test.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(ds.export('xlsx'))
```

I see that you have raised a bug on the project's issue tracker.  While this behaviour arguably isn't a bug, it would certainly be an improvement if the code emitted a more meaningful error message.